# How to compare column against itself?

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

As you'll quickly gather, I'm very new to SQL. So, I have a number of tables, one is a list of movies with corresponding titles and movieids, and another is a list of ratings (0-5) which has every rating any user has ever submitted and the movieid which they attach to. I am wanting to compare the average rating for every movie with the average rating of every other movie and generate a table with the results. So far I have:

```
    SELECT movies.movieid as movieid1, movies.movieid as movieid2, 1 - ((ABS(AVG(ratings.rating) - AVG(ratings.rating)))/5) as average
    FROM movies
    JOIN ratings
        ON movies.movieid = ratings.movieid
    GROUP BY movies.movieid;
```

However this is only comparing every movie to itself and thus giving an average rating comparison of 1.000 to all movies. How can I compare every movieid to every other unique movieid instead of comparing them to themselves?
For reference,

[image: this is what I am expecting one row of output to look like]

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `/ 5` meant to be there for?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result into your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get an average over the whole table, use a window function.

For example, the following gives the average of all movies' average rating...

```
AVG(AVG(ratings.rating)) OVER ()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the average rating with a group by

```sql
select movie_id, avg(rating) as rating from ratings group by movie_id
```

you can use cross join to get all the combinations of movies

```sql
select a.movie_id, b.movie_id from 
movies as a cross join movies as b
```

putting it together using a with statement

```sql
with avg_rating as ( 
  select movie_id, avg(rating) as rating from ratings group by movie_id
)

select a.movie_id, b.movie_id, a.rating / b.rating 
from avg_rating as a cross join avg_rating as b 
where a.movie_id <> b.movie_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare movies to other movies, you need a self-join operation. This would give you all pairs of ratings.

```
SELECT r1.rating first_rating
       r1.movieid first_movieid,
       r2.rating second_rating,
       r2.movieid second_movieid
  FROM ratings r1 
  JOIN ratings r2 ON r2.movieid < r1.movieid
```

The magic is in the ON clause. The inequality prevents the result from comparing movies to themselves, and `<` makes sure the comparisons aren't duplicated Forrest Gump::Avatar and Avatar::Forrest Gump.

If you have a lot of rows this will be slow. O(n squared).

Answer (score 0):

> I am wanting to compare the average rating for every movie with the average rating of every other movie and generate a table with the results.

If you want to compare the average ratings of two movies to each other, then you want something like this:

```
with r as (
      select movieid, avg(rating) as avg_rating
      from ratings r
      group by movieid
     )
select r1.movieid, r2.movieid, r1.avg_rating, r2.avg_rating
from r r1 join
     r r2
     on r1.movieid < r2.movieid;
```

You can then perform whatever arithmetic you want on the ratings.